# Calling CPP function from C File doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, c, qt, callback

I have a QT application which is written in c and c++. I tried to call a CPP function from C file. When I tried to call my callback function with a qpushbutton from UI, It works but when  I tried to call my callback function in the main, It does not work correctly. What is the problem according to the below codes? Thx.

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("ftp");
    url.setHost("192.168.1.2");
    url.setUserName("ftpadmin");
    url.setPassword("password");
    url.setPath("");
    FtpUploadManager *mFtpManager = new FtpUploadManager(url);
    mFtpManager->addFile("/home/user/Desktop/a.txt");
}
```

fileanalyzer.cpp

```
static inline void notify_ftp_manager(void *user,char* FileName)
{
    FileAnalyzer* _this = (FileAnalyzer*)(user);
    QString abc = QString(FileName);
    _this->m_FtpManager->addFile(abc);
}

FileAnalyzer::FileAnalyzer(QString path, QString prefix)
{ 
    QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("ftp");
    url.setHost("192.168.1.2");
    url.setUserName("ftpadmin");
    url.setPassword("password");
    url.setPath("");
    m_FtpManager = new FtpUploadManager(url, this);
    set_ftp_callback_function(notify_ftp_manager, this);
}
```

fileanalyzer.h

```
class FileAnalyzer: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FtpUploadManager *m_FtpManager ;
}
```

callbackfunction.c

```
CALLBACKFUNCTION ftp_callback;
void *ftp_callback_user;

void callbackfunction()
{
    if(ftp_callback != NULL && ftp_callback_user != NULL)
        {
        ftp_callback(ftp_callback_user,"a.txt");
        }
}

void set_ftp_callback_function(CALLBACKFUNCTION callbackfnc, void* ftp_callback_caller_user)
{
    ftp_callback = callbackfnc;
    ftp_callback_user = ftp_callback_caller_user;
}
int main()
{
      callbackfunction();
}
```

callbackfunction.h

```
typedef void (*CALLBACKFUNCTION)(void *user,char* fileName);
void set_ftp_callback_function(CALLBACKFUNCTION callbackfnc, void* ftp_callback_caller_user);
```

Comment: Are these two separate programs? Where is the `MainWindow` object created? I don't see it in `main()`.

Comment: Somehow the button has to be clicked before calling `callbackfunction()`, which to me is called first thing when the program starts.

Comment: Side note: To be safe, you should set `ftp_callback` and `ftp_callback_user` to `nullptr` when they are declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code didn't work because of the static method which I wrote for the callback function. When I changed the static function to class function, It worked! But I still don't know why static method did not work.